# Telerik Load on demand RadOrgChart not loading nodes after 3 levels

Tags: asp.net, telerik

In Telerik Load on demand RadOrgChart, I'm Loading data through server.
It will take up to 2 levels of data on every time click of each node. but data is coming properly from server,but problem is nodes not generated for those data. what should I do to get it properly?

[image: here is screen shot]

```
private void CreateTeams() {
    teams = new DataTable();
    teams.Columns.Add("UniqueID");
    teams.Columns.Add("ReportsTo");
    teams.Columns.Add("Collapsed");
    var myList = (List < NodeViewModel > ) Session["items"];

    foreach(var nodeitem in myList) {
        if (nodeitem.IsManager == true && nodeitem.level == 0) {
            teams.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                nodeitem.EmployeeBadge, null, "0"
            });
        } else {
            teams.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                nodeitem.EmployeeBadge, nodeitem.ManagerBadge, "1"
            });
        }
    }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if (Request.Cookies["badgeName"] != null) {
        var value = Request.Cookies["badgeName"].Value;
        EmployeeRepository obj = new EmployeeRepository();
        var myList = (List < NodeViewModel > ) Session["items"];
        try {
            obj.CreateLevel(new NodeViewModel() {
                EmployeeBadge = value
            }, myList);
            logger.Info("OrgChart:Page_Load()::success");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.Error(string.Concat("OrgChart:Page_Load()::", ex.Message));
            logger.Error(string.Concat("OrgChart:Page_Load()::", ex.StackTrace));
        }
        Response.Cookies["badgeName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }
    CreateTeams();
    CreateEmployees();


    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.NodeBindingSettings.DataFieldID = "UniqueID";
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.NodeBindingSettings.DataFieldParentID = "ReportsTo";
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.NodeBindingSettings.DataCollapsedField = "Collapsed";
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.NodeBindingSettings.DataGroupCollapsedField = "Collapsed";
    //RadOrgChart1.RenderedFields.NodeFields.Add(new Telerik.Web.UI.OrgChartRenderedField() { DataField = "Team" });
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.NodeBindingSettings.DataSource = teams;
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.GroupItemBindingSettings.DataFieldID = "EmployeeID";
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.GroupItemBindingSettings.DataFieldNodeID = "UniqueID";
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.GroupItemBindingSettings.DataTextField = "Name";
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.GroupItemBindingSettings.DataImageUrlField = "ImageUrl";
    RadOrgChart1.GroupEnabledBinding.GroupItemBindingSettings.DataSource = employees;

    RadOrgChart1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your problem is.

Comment: I am using RadOrgChart demand on load control from Telerik.

Onclick of the plus mark on every level I am fetching new levels of employee from my database.

After 3 levels, the plus mark doesn't show up. Instead of the plus mark, the loading symbol i.e., the spinning circle appears and I won't be able to fetch any further levels of employee below those nodes.

Comment: createTeams() method will create team of employees, ..so onclick of + mark im passing id from script to some reusable class ,from there again data will passing to createTeams(), so it will bring  2 levels of new data with already loaded one. but those data is not loading to telerik orgchart thats why that spinnning symbol is coming(as shown screen shot)